# ppm install failed: The PPD does not provide code to install for this platform

Tags: perl

I need to install Win32-GuiTest. I downloaded the package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/winguitest/, but when I try to run

```
PPM> install C:\temp\win32-guitest.ppd
```

it is saying

> ppm install failed: The PPD does not provide code to install for this platform

Can anybody tell how to install a module or package in Perl in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, [ActiveState isn't able to build Win32-GuiTest](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Win32-GuiTest/) for stable releases of Perl. Add the [Bribes repository](http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppmdir.html#Win32-GuiTest) instead, instructions are there.