# Why it pop ups Perl Package Manager instead of ppm> on terminal on writting ppm at terminal

Tags: perl, win32gui, gui-testing

I am trying to install Win32 GuiTest in my Windows8 (x64) I am using ActivePerl (Perl 5 version 20 subverion1) I am following this link: http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest-1.60/lib/Win32/GuiTest.pm .

I check perl -v and it shows the version (so works properly) but the problem is when i try to do "ppm" then i have a Perl Package Manager window pop up rather then some thing like this on terminal :

```
PPM interactive shell (2.0) - type 'help' for available commands.
    PPM>
```

Actually I have no idea why it pop ups Perl package manager instead of these command on terminal so that i would be able to folow the next steps termianl which are  given on that  link.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using version 4 of PPM.

PPM version 4 is a complete rewrite. In version 4 the command line shell has been replaced with a graphical user interface.

So before version 4 on typing `ppm` the command line package manager used to open, but now it opens GUI of package manager.

**Invoking ppm without arguments brings up the graphical user interface**, but ppm can also be used as a command line tool where the first argument provide the name of the sub-command to invoke.

You can try:

```
ppm install C:\temp\win32-guitest.ppd
```

Edit: See the linked answer on how to install Win32-GuiTest in ActiveState. ([ppm install failed: The PPD does not provide code to install for this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877463/ppm-install-failed-the-ppd-does-not-provide-code-to-install-for-this-platform)).

[image]

Comment: C:\temp>ppm install C:\temp\win32-guitest.ppd
ppm install failed: The PPD does not provide code to install for this platform

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to use Perl 5.12 and 1.58 version of Win32::GuiTest or just downgrade to 5.16. You can open GUI of PPM and see there if it's available to install on your platform.

Comment: are sure if i install if i install 5.16 on my Windows8 then it will successfully install Win32-GuiTest downloaded from this link : search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest-1.60/lib/Win32/…  (PLEASE SEE INSTALLATION PART OF THIS LINK) because i installed and uninstalled 3 times different version ..none of them worked yet –

Comment: I installed perl 5.16.2 and again followed documentation but again same errors. i also added the bribes repository but smae error. could you please help me ? i am under serious problems as deadlines are passing by.